# ActionScript 3.0 Objects Null on Stage

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, null, target

I'm creating a game where the user bakes a cake. If the user drags something (for example a jug of water) onto the next object (e.g saucepan) it should disappear from stage. The section of code in question is:

```
function mouseDownHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
event.currentTarget.startDrag(true);
}
function mouseUpHandler(event:MouseEvent):void{
var obj = event.currentTarget;
var target = obj.dropTarget;
if (target != null){
test_match(target, obj);
}
obj.stopDrag();
trace(dropTarget);
}
function test_match(target, obj){
if (target == saucePan && obj == jug)
{
removeChild(obj);
}
}
```

The trace inside the mouseUpHandler function shows up "null" whenever I drop the jug on an object on the stage, hense why I don't think the code executes and removes the jug from stage.

Answer (score 0):

obj.dropTarget  vs. dropTarget
These are two different things.

Comment: objects on stage are still null when changed to dropTarget

Comment: Yes, because it has nothing to do with any object on the stage. You never declared dropTarget anywhere. You confused it with obj.dropTarget, hence my answer about a difference between them. obj.dropTarget access the property of an object. dropTarget alone is just some random text in your code that happens to be interpreted as null.

Comment: I'm still confused. Is there any way you could shine some light onto this for me? I still don't understand why I can drag the objects around on the screen but they output null? How should I be declaring dropTarget?

Comment: The objects are not null. You are making a wrong conclusion based on a trace that makes no sense. You trace(dropTarget), but you could also trace(somethingElse) or whatever. It would be as related to your display objects as dropTarget: not at all. If you want to know if the dropTarget of the object "obj" is null, you have to refer to is via obj.dropTarget The "obj." in front of dropTarget makes all the difference. It's the difference between asking "What's name?" and "What's your/his/their name?". How would you answer the first question?

Comment: but I am referring to it as obj.dropTarget? I'm so confused.. Don't think I'm gona get my head round this one. As far as I can see and understand it should execute fine

Comment: At least in the code you provided with the question, you don't, there's no "obj." in trace(dropTarget); If you have new code now and the problem persist please edit your question.